# Get unique results from two tables OR How to MINUS two Tables in laravel by ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have Two Tables Fee and Bill_Fee . Bill_Fee has been made to resolve the many to many relationship between Fee and Bill.

```
Fee
----------
id    
amt  
student_id

Bill_Fee
----------
fee_id   
bill_id
```

First the `Fee` table should be selected with the help of `student_id` and then i need to `MINUS` as a `set(A={1,2,4,6,8} B={1,2,6,8,9,0}) A-B={4}` Like this so that if the `fee_id` exists in `bill fee` the details of those fees should not be extracted. and Those `fee_id` which are not in `Bill` should be extracted

Comment: you should use left join or sub query

Comment: left join just does the opposite of what i want to do

Comment: below i have added answer in details, try below queries and update in comments

Comment: See about JOINs, and LEFT JOIN in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sub query` & `NOT EXISTS` like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Fee AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Bill_Fee AS b 
  WHERE a.id=b.fee_id
)
```

there is multiple way to execute query in laravel

you can execute query like this

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT ____________";
$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sqlQuery));
```

Comment: how to use this query in laravel

Comment: the first query worked but the second query didn't. The second query returned both matching and not matching  results.

Comment: how do i use where in fee so that it selects fee with student id and then Minus with Bill_Fee.